# Changing daylight savings time to standard time in R

Tags: r, timezone, posix, dst

I am trying to convert local times (U.S. Mountain Time Zone) to UTC.  R seems to be doing some strange things regarding the transition from MDT to MST.  Isn't this switch supposed to occur at 2am local time?  R is doing this at 1:10 a.m., in my case (see below output).  My times are defined as POSIXct series.

```
> subdata$Date[11:15]
[1] "2008-11-02 00:55:00 MDT" "2008-11-02 01:00:00 MDT" "2008-11-02
01:05:00 MDT" "2008-11-02 01:10:00 MST" "2008-11-02 01:15:00 MST"

five_min_data$Date <- as.POSIXct(as.character  
(five_min_data$Date),tz="America/Denver")
```

Any help regarding what I could be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I can replicate this on R 3.4.2, Windows7. `as.POSIXct(c("2008-11-02 01:05:00", "2008-11-02 01:10:00"), tz="America/Denver")` Not sure I understand what is going on though.

Comment: Try to get the whole sequence of dates from 1am to 3am, you will probably see duplicated values. In november the date change is backwards, so you should see duplicated values. wWhen I create a Posix sequence of theses dates, I get the right output: `"2008-11-02 01:59:00 MDT" "2008-11-02 01:00:00 MST"`.

Comment: @agenis - it is mighty confusing. 01:05 and 01:10 are valid in both MDT and MST. I can't comprehend a scenario where one should be MDT and the other MST though. I'm clearly missing something. `diff(as.POSIXct(c("2008-11-02 01:05:00", "2008-11-02 01:10:00"), tz="America/Denver"))` gives 1hr5mins for instance.

Comment: @thelatemail I don't get why you're confused. This specific day is 25 hours long, so it's normal to see this 1h time difference no? Run the whole seq.POSIXt to see what's happening.

Comment: @agenis - I'm confused because surely text timestamps that are valid in both standard or daylight-savings should both be attributed to the same timezone. I can look at the full list from midnight to 3am and everything is fine, I can see the time roll back. Agreed. But why on earth should two *valid* text timestamps 5 minutes apart get separated by an extra hour?

Comment: yeah you're right I see what you mean and the OP mean. This is weird like `diff(as.POSIXct(c("2008-11-02 01:08:29", "2008-11-02 01:08:30"), tz="America/Denver"))`. why this is happening at this specific time.

Comment: Though this artefact does not seem to exist when you use lubridate functions like ymd_hms

Comment: @aegenis - It can be traced all the way back to `strptime(c("2008-11-02 01:08:29", "2008-11-02 01:08:30"), format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "America/Denver")` which unfortunately goes to compiled code.

Comment: Good to know it's not just me.  Agenis, How are you using ymd_hms?  I'll try an xts or zoo series, and see if that works, too.

Comment: On testing a few different years, it seems that R doesn't seem to be consistent in its rules of how to parse ambiguous values.  The cutover seems to be arbitrary.  The times >= 01:00 and < 02:00 are indeed ambiguous, but you'd think it would be consistent in how it handled it.